# PHP - copy causing HTTP error 500

Tags: php, centos

PHP on execute causing HTTP error 500. I have chmod -R 777 on driver_license.exe.

[image]

```
<?php
$agent= $_GET['agentid'];
$userid = $_GET['userid'];

$file = "/home/www/file/driver_license.exe";
$path = "/home/www/file/";
"
$newfile ="driver_license_userid_1.exe";

$file_to_save = $path . $newfile;
if (!copy($file, $file_to_save)) {
    echo "FAILED";
}
else {
  echo "<a href=https://download.example.com/{$newfile}>DOWNLOAD & INSTALL</a>";
}
```

Comment: You have extra `"` after `$path = "/home/www/file/";`.Is it TYPO mistake?Or you have it there in your code?

Comment: Still it fails. When the " was removed (TYPO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You have extra `"` after `$path = "/home/www/file/";`.Remove that.

2.You forget to add quotes around `href`.Add that

So code need to be:-

```
<?php
$agent= $_GET['agentid'];
$userid = $_GET['userid'];

$file = "/home/www/file/driver_license.exe";
$path = "/home/www/file/";
 //" need to remove or comment
$newfile ="driver_license_userid_1.exe";

$file_to_save = $path . $newfile;
if (!copy($file, $file_to_save)) {
    echo "FAILED";
}
else {
  echo "<a href='https://download.example.com/{$newfile}'>DOWNLOAD & INSTALL</a>"; // ' added around href
}
```

***Important Note:-*** folders need to be permissioned for access (give `077` permission for `home,www and file` folders)

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 428032 Jan  8 08:13` file at driver_license.exe

Comment: folder also have to be permission for access (077 for home,www and file )

Comment: Thank you working perfectly now. was required `chmod -R 777 /home/www/file`

Comment: @YumYumYum  glad to help you